# Recursive Function correct way to return

Tags: c++, function, recursion

I'm learning recursion in C++, and I was wondering whether there is a difference between these two recursive functions. Is it necessary to have an else statement? Which is more efficient?

Thank you for your help.

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);
}



int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * fact(n - 1);
}
```

Comment: The two ways will probably generate identical assembler code.

Comment: It is never required to have an else statement, but sometimes you will need it for a given structure. Your first function, with no else statement, is fine.

Comment: It is entirely up to personal preference and readability. You could even do `return n == 1 ? 1 : n * fact(n-1);` if you wanted.

Comment: Explicit `else` statements will help with readability; thus, helping you cover all the cases. Not covering all the cases could mean a ton of painful debugging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are exactly the same. The `else` is not needed because the function is exited after a `return` statement is reached. To double-check they are identical on your machine, you could do a timing comparison, but they will probably compile to the same thing.